# In Unity, can I get the position of all particles in a VFX Effect system in a C# script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gpu

A VFX Graph Effect particle system is computed on the GPU, while our C# scripts are computed on the CPU.

Passing data back and forth between the CPU and GPU **is possible**. To pass data from the GPU back to the CPU, I would typically write to a buffer on the GPU, then pass that buffer/texture to the CPU to process it.

How can this be done in Unity and/or C#?

My goal is to store all the locations of the particles in my VFX Graph, and compute against them in my C# script. I would likely not do this every frame as typically accessing a buffer from the GPU on your CPU is a bit costly, but likely every few frames.

Note - while I appreciate it, **I'm not looking for alternative solutions to using VFX Graph**. I'm aware that usually for computing against particles you can use Unity's Shuriken Particle System or GameObject pooling. For this question, I am specifically looking to access VFX effect particle locations in C#.